# Is there a good work-around for Selenium IDE errors?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, selenium-ide

While testing some scripts with Selenium, I keep running into errors in certain steps. Normally the work-around is to do something manually to set it back-on-track.

My question is; Does Selenium IDE have some sort of built-in redirect function, so that if ONE step throws an error, it can run a different line of code to correct the issue. I've only worked with Selenium IDE so I wouldn't know if any of the other modules have this type of work-around.

Would this be achievable using seperate modules or scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
But that doesn't mean you can't automate it.

One of the reasons is that Selenium is not a test-framework. Besides, if your test steps are non-deterministic, I'd consider it good practise to implement the non-deterministic part as part of the test step, not in a global hook in your test framework. You could use a `try-catch` or a poll/check before running into an error.